# PreferredLocations in Cosmos DB SDK V2

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Does Cosmos DB automatically set `PreferredLocations`? For example when new regions are added/deleted.

Or users have to set it themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, the most optimal endpoint will be chosen by the SQL SDK to perform write and read operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api#connecting-to-a-preferred-region-using-the-sql-api

This is based on the configuration of your account, region availability. If you don't specify the PreferredLocation property, then all requests (read and write) will be served from your account's current write region.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

PreferredLocations must be specified for high availability. EnableEndpointDiscovery along with PreferredLocations allows you to leverage Cosmos DB failover capabilities.

When the value of this EnableEndpointDiscovery is true, the SDK will automatically discover the current write and read regions to ensure requests are sent to the correct region based on the regions specified in the PreferredLocations property. Default value is true indicating endpoint discovery is enabled.